# How to make a javascript function with optional callback paramters

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get my head around how to make a jasvascript function with optional callback parameters

I'm not sure of the technical term for what i'm trying to achieve, so it makes searching for the solution difficult, however this is probably useful for other newcomers

I'e, usage would be as follows

```
    MyFunction({
        start: function() {
        },

        end: function() {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please describe better what you expect from such a function? How is different from a function with any other optional parameter? What's specific about "optional callbacks"?

Comment: what is the problem? All JS parameters are optional already.

Comment: Are the callbacks optional or do the callbacks have the option of accepting parameters?

Comment: wow down voted already, the real usage of this function is it will have about 10 events that can be optionally subscribed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for you with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/0csnrv7p/

Code:

```
function myFunction(options) {
    // You need something like this line if you want to handle the case
    // where there are no arguments at all.  If options is undefined then
    // trying to access a property within it results in an error.
    options = options || {}; 

    if (typeof options.start === 'function') {
        options.start();
    }

    // ...
    // do stuff
    // ...

    if (typeof options.end === 'function') {
        options.end();
    }
}


myFunction({
    start: function() {
        console.log('start');
    },
    end: function() {
        console.log('end');
    }
});
```

And here's a link with more information: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways I guess. Either you have a default option, something like:

```
function MyFunction(options) {
    var defaults = {
        start: function(){},
        end: function(){}
    };

    // use jQuery.extend() or whatever you want
    options = extend(default, options);

    // Call a callback
    options.start();
}
```

This way it's always safe to call the callback, weither or not the argument has been set.

Or you can check if the callback is set, and if it is call it.

```
function MyFunction(options)

    // Call a callback
    if('start' in options && typeof options.start === 'function') options.start();
}
```